# Remove query string parameters from a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with urls. Example:

```
"http://www.examplesite1.com?test=test"
"http://www.examplesite2.com?test=test"
"http://www.examplesite3.com?test=test"
"http://www.examplesite4.com?test=test"
```

The query param is common and I would like to remove it and have a result like this:

```
"http://www.examplesite1.com"
"http://www.examplesite2.com"
"http://www.examplesite3.com"
"http://www.examplesite4.com"
```

Comment: `sub("\\?test=test$", "", df$urls)` for example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sub`:

```
vec <- c("http://www.examplesite1.com?test=test",
         "http://www.examplesite2.com?a=b")

sub("\\?.+", "", vec)
# [1] "http://www.examplesite1.com" "http://www.examplesite2.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
df$MyCol <- sapply(df$MyCol, function(x) strsplit(x,"[?]")[[1]])
```